# how can i show just spicific url in barre link with django

Tags: python, django

i devlop an application to a blog using django
The problem is when I open a link to a publication
For example, https: // localhost: 8000 / article / 89 /
And I want to open another link to a brochure and see this
https: // localhost: 8000 / article / 89 / article / 80 /
Whenever you click a link, the same thing happens
Is there a solution please

> view.py articles

```
def show_article(request, id):

post = get_object_or_404(articles, id=id)
add = comment_put.objects.all().filter(user_put = id).order_by('-id')
art = articles.objects.get(pk = id)
first = articles.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
three = articles.objects.order_by('-id')[:4]

is_liked = False

if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    is_liked = True

context = {
     'art': art,
     'add': add,
     'post': post,
     'first': first,
     'three': three,
     'is_liked': is_liked,
     'total_likes': post.total_likes(),


      }


return render(request, 'home/article.html', context)
```

> urls.py

```
  url(r'article/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.show_article, name='show_article'),
```

> article.html

```
<!-- column -->
 {% for sd in solo1 %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">

 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
 <img class="card-img-top" src="{{sd.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
 <div class="card-body">
     <a class="" href="article/{{sd.id}}" style="color:#212529; text-decoration: none !important"><p class="card-text">{{sd.title}}</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
<!--end column -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please show your template where you are including the link.

Comment: show me how to you write url in template

Comment: <a class="" href="article/{{sd.id}}" style="color:#212529; text-decoration: none !important"><p class="card-text">{{sd.title}}</p></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start your link from slash! /

```
<a class="" href="/article/{{sd.id}}" style="color:#212529; text-decoration: none !important"><p class="card-text">{{sd.title}}</p></a>
```

when you have http://example.com/page/1/ in your browser and link like page/2 you will have this result http://example.com/page/1/page/2 and when your link is '/page2' you will have http://example.com/page/2/

Comment: Thank you brother, the problem has been solved
I wish you a happy day

Comment: Nice to hear. Add a plus (up) to this answer and green checkbox if I helped to you